# how to count number of columns and rows in all tables group by table?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I can't find a mistake in my query:

```
SELECT
u.Table_Name, 
count(distinct c.Column_Name), 
sum(u.num_rows)    
FROM User_Tab_Columns c, User_Tables u    
WHERE   u.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME    
group by u.Table_Name;
```

the result is:

```
TABLE_NAME                     COUNT(DISTINCTC.COLUMN_NAME) SUM(U.NUM_ROWS)    
------------------------------ ---------------------------- ---------------
DEPT                                                      3              12     
EMP                                                       8             112
```

and it should be:

```
 TABLE_NAME                     COUNT(DISTINCTC.COLUMN_NAME) SUM(U.NUM_ROWS)    
    ------------------------------ ---------------------------- ---------------
    DEPT                                                      3              4     
    EMP                                                       8             14
```

So the query multiple number of rows and number of columns but I don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of rows is per table, you can simply group by it:

```
SELECT
u.Table_Name, 
count(*), 
u.num_rows    
FROM User_Tab_Columns c, User_Tables u    
WHERE   u.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME    
group by u.Table_Name, u.num_rows;
```

Comment: The presence of `distinct` is meaningless. Table cannot have more than one column with the same name.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - true - have removed this from the query - and changed to count(*) instead.

Comment: Also the table statistic must be gathered before executing the above query. Otherwise the `num_rows` might contain wrong data.

Comment: Precious comments.Thank you all.